# What formation-keeping maneuvers are required by MMS?

Tags: nasa, station-keeping, formation-flying

The [Magnetospheric MultiScale (MMS) mission](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/mms/spacecraft/orbit.html) is a NASA mission consisting of four satellites arranged (at apogee) in a tetrahedral formation. [According to this 2015 source](https://phys.org/news/2015-10-nasa-mms-spacecraft-tightest-formation.html):

> On Oct. 15, 2015, a NASA mission broke its own record: the four satellites of its Magnetospheric Multiscale mission are now flying at their smallest separation [~10km], the tightest multi-spacecraft formation ever flown in orbit.

What formation-keeping maneuvers* are required to maintain, in the presence of perturbations, the tetrahedral formation at apogee? Was a reference satellite chosen or is there an central orbit** that formation-keeping and station-keeping are referenced to?

*Assume an audience that is familiar with nominal station-keeping maneuvers for single satellites.

**There were two phases to the scientific mission for MMS, each with a different reference orbit. If formation-keeping significantly differs based on these reference orbits, answering for just one of the phases is sufficient.